# About asterisk dialplan for external number

Tags: asterisk

Suppose this simple dialplan

```
[office-phones]
exten => 1001,1,Dial(PJSIP/alice)
exten => 1002,1,Dial(PJSIP/michael)

exten => _XXXXX.,1,Set(CALLERID(all)="Name Surname <123456789>")
same => n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN}@ASTERISK01)
```

ASTERISK01 is a sip phone registered to a FritzBox router
for external calls (my telco give connection error if directly from
asterisk).
My question is this: I want to define a pattern like this

```
exten => _XXXXX.,1,Set(CALLERID(all)="Name Surname <123456789>")
same => n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN}@ASTERISK01)
exten => _1005,1,Set(CALLERID(all)="Name Surname <123456789>")
same => n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN}@ASTERISK01)
```

So If I call 1005 it use the external line, is possible? I have tried but give me busy or refuse.